# Application of Riesz representation theorem and norm of linear functional.

Tags: functional-analysis, measure-theory, riesz-representation-theorem

I think the solution to this question somehow involves Riesz Representation Theorem, but I don't see how to apply it.

Suppose $\{X,\mathcal{M},\mu\}$ is a $\sigma-$ finite measure space, $1\leq p<\infty$ and $\phi$ in a continuous linear functional on $L^{p}(\mu)$.

a) Prove that if $1<p$ then there is an element $f\in L^{p}(\mu)$ such that $\mid\mid f\mid\mid_{p}=1$ and $\phi(f)=\mid\mid\phi\mid\mid$.
b) prove that a) need not be true when p=1

Comment: You know that $L^p(\mu)' \cong L^q(\mu)$, where $\frac{1}{p}+\frac{1}{q} = 1$, probably. From that representation of $\phi$, you can construct the desired $f$ for $1 < p < \infty$ (for $\phi = 0$, and arbitrary $f$ will do).

Comment: how can I prove $\mid\mid f\mid\mid_{p}=1$?

Comment: You _construct_ it so that it has norm $1$.

Comment: yes,Please help me how can I construct it?

Comment: How does $\phi$ look? What does the representation theorem say about that?

Comment: $phi:L_{p}\rightarrow F$ defined by $$\phi(g)=\int_{X} fg d\mu$$, where $f\in L_{q}$. From this I conclude that $\mid\mid\phi\mid\mid=\mid\mid f\mid\mid$

Comment: Right, and you want $$\int_X fg\,d\mu = \lVert f\rVert_q^{1-q}\int_X \lvert f\rvert^q\,d\mu.$$ Any idea what $g$ might look like to achieve that?

Comment: not,, actually my question start from here?

Comment: You certainly have the desired equality if you have the pointwise equality of the integrands, $$f(x)g(x) = \lVert f\rVert_q^{1-q}\lvert f(x)\rvert^q$$ for all $x$. How would you achieve that?

Answer (score 0):

For $1 < p < \infty$: If $\phi$ is a continuous linear functional on $L^{p}(\mu)$, then there exists $g \in L^{q}(\mu)$ such that
$$
                 \phi(f)=\int fg\,d\mu,\;\;\; \left[\int |g|^{q}\,d\mu\right]^{1/q} =\|\phi\|.
$$
See if you can figure out how to choose $f \in L^{p}$ to make the first integral look like the second, knowing that $1/p+1/q=1$, or $q/p+1=q$. See where it leads.